# a replacement to ad-hoc on the appstore

Tags: xcode, app-store

My company needs to upload an app to the store , that will only be available to 80 people over the world that will get the permission to **test** it.

The ad-hoc method requires their iphones id's to be register with the app, and obviously we dont have it.
Whats the best way, to upload the app to the store ,to let this people to get it ?
(NO, without just go to the review process of apple)

thanks.

Comment: like the non answer said. Enterprise app, host an .htm page on the web or a web site with simple out of box security for download. Or just give them a key to unlock and check for the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the enterprise developer program, Ad-Hoc distribution is the only way to limit your audience.

If you try to game the app store with an unreasonable high price and promo codes (limit of 50 codes per app version) Apple will kick you out of the review process in no time.

Use [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/) to get device IDs easier and deploy you app to the testers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, for the Adhoc, you must register their UDID devices.
You can upload the app in the AppStore, put it's price high, and give the prople that you want to test the app a redeem code that will download the app free, but i think the number of redeem code you have is 25. If you find anyway to do that, share it with us please.

Answer (score 0):

If the 80 people that will be testing/using the app are employees of the company, you should look into the [Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).  Enterprise development lets you deploy an internal app to employees of your organization that is not released to the App Store.  It essentially lets you build an Ad Hoc like version of your app that can then be installed on devices without the need to get UDIDs.

The cost is $299 instead of the normal $99 and there are a few caveats on whether or not your organization qualifies.  But if you do qualify, it vastly simplifies deploying an internal app and it gives you specifically what you were asking for - no review and no need to ask for UDIDs.  You can put the signed bundle up on a website and simply give people the URL to it for OTA installation, so you don't even need iTunes.

Alternatively, if the end users are not a part of your organization, you can also look into [developing Custom B2B Apps](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).  This one comes with a few more hoops to jump through and it also requires an Apple review, but it allows your app to be sold only to specific customers and doesn't put it in the App Store.  If you're already a developer with Apple, there's even [a WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=311) on it.